# Concat two <anonymous type: string a, string b> arrays

Tags: c#, linq, concatenation

I have following queries:

```
var query = (from el in l
                   where el.ID_Seal_From != "" && el.ID_Seal_From != null
                   select new
                   {
                       el.Conn_from,
                       el.ID_Seal_From
                   }).ToArray();


        var query2 = (from el in l
                     where el.ID_Seal_To != "" && el.ID_Seal_To != null
                     select new
                     {
                         el.Conn_to,
                         el.ID_Seal_To
                     }).ToArray();

var res = query.Concat(query2);
```

i need to join the result of them in order to work with the results. I've already tried to concat it as array and as list but i had no success.

The Error is:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> CS1929 "<anonymous type: string Conn_from, string ID_Seal_From>[]"
> does not contain a definition for "Concat", and the overload of the
> optimal extension method "ParallelEnumerable. Concat<<anonymous type:
> string Conn_to, string ID_Seal_To>>(ParallelQuery<<anonymous type:
> string Conn_to, string ID_Seal_To>>, IEnumerable<<anonymous type:
> string Conn_to, string ID_Seal_To>>)" requires a receiver of type
> "ParallelQuery<<anonymous type: string Conn_to, string ID_Seal_To>>".

Comment: `.Concat` can only concatenate identically typed sequences. Anonymous types only match in type if they contain the same properties of the same type in the same order, whereas yours have a mismatch between `from` and `to`. You can either rename the properties (`conn = el.Conn_from`), or use tuples instead (`(el.Conn_from, el.ID_Seal_From)`), these will match structurally.

Answer (score 0):

First make them have the same properties and Concat.

```
var query = (from el in l
                   where el.ID_Seal_From != "" && el.ID_Seal_From != null
                   select new
                   {
                       conn = el.Conn_from,
                       seal = el.ID_Seal_From
                   });


        var query2 = (from el in l
                     where el.ID_Seal_To != "" && el.ID_Seal_To != null
                     select new
                     {
                         conn = el.Conn_to,
                         seal = el.ID_Seal_To
                     });

var res = query.Concat(query2); // .ToArray() if you like
```

Comment: You shouldn't need `ToList()` *or* `ToArray()` there

Comment: @Canton, yes, could directly use the IEnumerable.

Comment: `and use a list instead to Concat` - why this? does concat not work without .ToList() ?

Comment: @RandRandom, read the previous one. You don't need to ask unnecessary questions.

Comment: `and use a list instead of Concat` - why this? does concat not work without .ToList() ?

Comment: @RandRandom, what is your problem?